# PHP string words to array

Tags: php, string, filter, trim

I need to take only full words from a string i mean full words = words with more then 4 chars.
Example of a string:

```
"hey hello man are you going to write some code"
```

I need to return to:

```
"hello going write some code"
```

Also i need to trim all of these words and put them into a simple array.

Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a regular expression to do it.

```
preg_replace("/\b\S{1,3}\b/", "", $str);
```

You could then put them into an array with `preg_split()`.

```
preg_split("/\s+/", $str);
```

Comment: how then to put them into array?

Comment: @Ispuk : `explode(' ', $string)`, see : http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Answer (score 6):

Depending on your full requirements and if you need the string array unmodified too, you could use `explode` for this, something like this would get your words into an array:

```
$str = "hey hello man are you going to write some code";
$str_arr = explode(' ', $str);
```

Then you can use `array_filter` to remove the words you don't want, like so:

```
function min4char($word) {
    return strlen($word) >= 4;
}
$final_str_array = array_filter($str_arr, 'min4char');
```

Otherwise if you don't need the unmodified array, you can use a regular expression to get all matches that are above a certain length using `preg_match_all`, or replace out the ones that are using `preg_replace`.

One final option would be to do it the basic way, use `explode` to get your array as per the first code example, and then loop over everything using `unset` to remove the entry from the array. But then, you'd also need to reindex (depending on your subsequent usage of the 'fixed' array), which could be inefficient depending on how large your array is.

EDIT: Not sure why there are claims that it does not work, see below for output of `var_dump($final_str_array)`:

```
array(5) { [1]=> string(5) "hello" [5]=> string(5) "going" [7]=> string(5) "write" [8]=> string(4) "some" [9]=> string(4) "code" }
```

@OP, to convert this back to your string, you can simply call `implode(' ', $final_str_array)` to get this output:

```
hello going write some code
```

Comment: +1, looks the cleanest to me.

Comment: Downvote for a solution that works, hurrah! Any particular reason? (EDIT: I hope this isn't about the Regex elitism)

Comment: I've been told once that a *working solution* is not always a *valid solution*. Other than that I don't see why someone would downvote your answer.

Comment: @tereško How so? Have you ran it? It works fine. Sorry for this - array(10) { [0]=> string(3) "hey" [1]=> string(5) "hello" [2]=> string(3) "man" [3]=> string(3) "are" [4]=> string(3) "you" [5]=> string(5) "going" [6]=> string(2) "to" [7]=> string(5) "write" [8]=> string(4) "some" [9]=> string(4) "code" } array(5) { [1]=> string(5) "hello" [5]=> string(5) "going" [7]=> string(5) "write" [8]=> string(4) "some" [9]=> string(4) "code" }

Comment: It must be nice to live in the world where only language is english and punctuation is part of the word.

Comment: @tereško Indeed, but based on the OP's exact requirements, this solution indeed works, and is flexible enough based on modification of the simple callback to be adapted for any other situation.

Answer (score 6):

Use `str_word_count()` http://php.net/manual/fr/function.str-word-count.php

```
str_word_count($str, 1)
```

Will return you a list of words, then count the ones with more than `n` letters using `strlen()`

The big advantage of using `str_word_count()` over other solutions such as `preg_match` or `explode` is that it will account for the punctuation and discard it from the final list of words.

Answer (score 1):

First, put them into an an array:

```
$myArr = explode(' ', $myString);
```

Then, loop through and assign only those with a length of 4 or greater to a new array:

```
$finalArr = array();

foreach ($myArr as $val) {
  if (strlen($val) > 3) {
    $finalArr[] = $val;
  }
}
```

Obviously, if you have commas and other special characters in your string, it gets trickier, but for a basic design, I think this gets you moving in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

```
$strarray = explode(' ', $str);
$new_str = '';
foreach($strarray as $word){
   if(strlen($word) >= 4)
      $new_str .= ' '.$word;
}
echo $new_str;
```

[Code Output](http://codepad.org/R12dohnz#output)

Answer (score 1):

No loops required, no nested function calls, no temporary arrays. Just 1 function call and a very simple regex.

```
$string = "hey hello man are you going to write some code";
preg_match_all('/\S{4,}/', $string, $matches);

//Printing Values
print_r($matches[0]);
```

[See it working](http://codepad.viper-7.com/egA3IP)

Comment: Wouldn't that also capture commas?

Comment: @BrianWarshaw It would capture anything that is not a whitespace character. The OP is not specific about what he wants in this respect. Obviously something like `\w` or a character class like `[a-zA-Z]` could be used to narrow it down to whatever is required.

Comment: Agreed--just pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$word = "hey hello man are you going to write some code";
$words = explode(' ', $word);
$new_word;
foreach($words as $ws)
{
    if(strlen($ws) > 4)
    {
        $new_word[] = $ws;
    }
}
echo "<pre>"; print_r($new_word);
?>
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use explode() and array_filter() with trim() + strlen() to achieve this. Try it and post your code if you're stuck.

Comment: Seems like a lot of code for something a regex will be fine :)

Comment: @PeeHaa Avoid regexes when you can. Here, it will make the code more maintainable / readable. See how rudi_visser's solution is more readable than alex's?

Comment: "Avoid regexes when you can" I'm sorry, but this is bullshit. And based on micro optimization.

Comment: Where did I speak about performance? Stay polite please. Anyway, compare upvotes between both solutions if you're not convinced.

Comment: You are truly saying that rudi's answer is more readable than alex's? Let's rephrase my last comment, but that is just idiotic.

Comment: Yes. min4char is more understandable than `/\b\S{1,3}\b/`, isn't it?

Comment: @PeeHaa: again , please stay polite, and backup your sayings with facts if you can.

Comment: The fact is that this is a nice example of where you should use a simple regex pattern.

Comment: Well, sorry but I find the other nicer: it looks more semantic to me: it filters out words in the array that are longer that 3 characters. alex's solution replaces 1 to 3 non-whitespace strings with nothing. But you're free to prefer the other solution if semantic is not a priority for you. Just dont assert regexes are better because they are shorter.